# Unable to locate package php7.1-soap

Tags: apt, package-management, php

I have installed PHP 7.1 on my Ubuntu 16.04 and now I want to install the SOAP module. However, `apt-get install php7.1-soap` results in: `Unable to locate package php7.1-soap`.

I also tried `apt-cache search --names-only ^php7.1-apt-cache search --names-only ^php7.1-` and then I got a rather short list of modules that did not include SOAP.

I saw at some place the advice to run: `add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php`.

However, when I did that my system installed PHP 7.2 with the next update. That effectively crashed my system and I had to restore a backup.

Comment: Php soap v. 7.1 is only on 17.10 Artful (EOL now). See [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=php%20soap). Official 16.04 LTS includes PHP 7.0. [Sury's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php?field.series_filter=xenial) does not have Soap packages for 16.04 LTS. Are you sure that you need 7.1? Maybe 7.0 from official repositories will be enough...

Comment: this is not right, just checked and you CAN install php7.1-soap with surys PPA

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding Surys PPA won't crash your system. 
Installing some packages and overriding existing ones as a result - MIGHT (but usually won't).

My usual approach is to install all PHP versions from Sury's PPA because I need to run a few PHP versions running next to each other on the same system.

Please first remove all ubuntu PHP packages before installing the ones Sury provides. All should be good afterward.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

This should allow you to install soap for php7.1 with

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-soap
```

I just checked this on 16.04.4.

Comment: updated answer, because just checked on digitalocean 16.04 droplet, adding sury PPA DOES allow you to install php7.1-soap, so just added the command I used to install it. If your php project requires php7.1, using 7.0 is no-go.

Comment: OK, this really seems to work according to the output of `apt-cache policy php7.1-soap` I got after I added the repository. The package is not listed on the [PPA webpage](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/) though…